# C - How to Obtain a Time in C Using a Struct

Tags: c, struct

I have an issue in my C project which involves an assortment of schedules, and each schedule needs a date. I obtain it using a struct.  Now I would like to delete all the old schedules, so in order to do this the code nees to:

- Get the present time
- Run my list to compare whether (Date(now) > Date(old)).  If true, the code will delete the pertinent schedule.

The primary issue concerns how to get the real time, and pass it to my struct.  Can anyone help in this regard?

The code that attempts to get the real time and put into a struct is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct date Date;
typedef struct hour Hour;

struct hour{

    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;

};

struct date{

    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    Hour hour;

};

int main (void) {

    Date date;

    //char buff[100];
    time_t now = time(0);    
    strftime (date, 100, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));
    printf ("%s\n", date);

    //I want to put localtime(&now) on date instead buff that is a char!
    //To me compare after

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: localtime returns a struct for you https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime

Comment: How can i fill my struct with the localtime return?

Comment: by copying the fields form one struct to the other, but invent a new struct, just use the c standard one

Comment: i trying but its not working!

Comment: Note that `struct tm` has some eccentric encoding for the fields — `tm_year` is the current year minus 1900, and `tm_mon` counts from January is 0 through December is 11. You have two main options. One is to convert from your structure to `struct tm`; the other is to convert from `struct tm` to your structure.  Both are doable.  You'll also need to write one or two comparator functions — to compare two (pointers to const) of your structures, or two (pointers to const) of `struct tm`.  Given the finite and small ranges valid for each field, you don't have to worry about overflow on subtraction.

Comment: I'm mildly curious: why `struct hour` rather than `struct time` (and why `Hour` instead of `Time`)?  And why not have a `struct date` with date only, and a `struct datetime` with date and time?  However, these are minor design issues, and don't affect the immediate workability of your code.

Comment: you have to show code that you tried but isnt working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `struct tm` together with `localtime` to get the individual values for day, month, year, and so on. Then you can either copy the values to your own struct, or you can use `struct tm` directly and throughout in your code. Note that - when copying to your struct - some values need to be adapted if you want to have, for example, `2017` as a years value instead of `117`:

```
int main (void) {

    Date date;

    char buff[100];
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm now_t = *localtime(&now);
    strftime (buff, 100, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", &now_t);

    date.year = now_t.tm_year + 1900; // years since 1900
    date.month = now_t.tm_mon + 1;  // months since January [0-11]
    date.day = now_t.tm_mday;  // day of month [1-31]

    date.hour.hour = now_t.tm_hour;
    date.hour.minute = now_t.tm_min;
    date.hour.second = now_t.tm_sec;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was confuse where to use the struct tm, now its working!

Comment: @pm100: yes; but it's nothing wrong with the use of `strtime`, so I kept it but adapted OP's code to write to `buff`.

Comment: @GabrielGomes Note that 1 day a year may have 25 hours in it due to daylight time and so `date` may benefit with a DST member.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wishes to store a unix timestamp (the number of seconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970 UTC) in a date structure.  Rather than create more structures to hold the "broken-down"  date and time information (see this [solution](http://codepad.org/tKNYpWSP)), one could fill a date tm structure using localtime_r(), as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
  time_t seconds;
  struct tm date;
  struct tm * resultp;
  char buffer[80];
  const char *format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S";

  setenv("TZ", "PST8PDT", 1);
  tzset();

  // get and store current local date and time ...
  seconds = time(NULL);
  resultp = localtime_r( &seconds, &date );

  // ... and safely display it
  if (resultp != NULL) {  
    strftime (buffer, 80, format, resultp);
    printf("Current local date and time: %s",buffer);
  }

  return(0);
}
```

see [demo](http://codepad.org/xJNALfqE)

localtime() is certainly an option but it entails a little more effort. One has to take care to dereference its return value, a pointer to a tm structure and then assign it to a user-supplied structure.  The reason for these maneuvers owes to localtime() storing data in a statically allocated structure which is thus transitory in nature.

Note: if one wishes to prepare the newly assigned tm structure for display with strftime(), the code needs to pass the address of the structure as the function's fourth parameter.

Instead this example relies on localtime_r() which advantageously stores data in an enduring structure.  The function's return value is a pointer to this structure which certainly is convenient for subsequently passing as a  parameter to strftime(). The tradeoff with using localtime_r() is that one needs to specify the timezone and call tzset()  in order to get the correct time, especially when daylight saving is in effect.